# gpg: can't open `–': "No such file or directory" during "wget ... apt-key add" upgrading Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, wget, gpg

I tried to upgrade my Kali Linux by following their steps.

On this command:

```
wget -q -O - https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc | apt-key add
```

I got output:

```
gpg: can't open `–': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Make sure the hyphen in `-O -` is an ASCII hyphen (0x2d) and not some other character like Ndash. The error message suggests you copy-pasted the wrong character there.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed when I copy/paste this part of the gpg message:

```
... open `–': No ...
```

into `od -c -`, I get:

```
0000000   o   p   e   n       ` 342 200 223   '   :       N   o  \n
```

which indicates that you used an [en dash](http://graphemica.com/%E2%80%93) (`–`) instead of a [hyphen-minus](http://graphemica.com/-), or ASCII 45 (`-`). A tiny visual difference, but an important one to Unix tools.

A real dash would look like this in `od`:

```
0000000   o   p   e   n       '   -   '   :       N   o  \n
```